# StarCraft2: is it possible to build planetary fortress and orbital command in one command center?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran, command-center, orbital-command

Is it possible to build planetary fortress and orbital command in one command center?

I didn't think is possible, but I saw some threads that tell build OC and then PF...

Am I correctly understand that it is possible to build both of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [it's not possible](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Planetary_fortress) (Wish it were, that would rule.)

People who build PF usually do it as a cheap way to defend an early expansion. But OC is better to start because your start should be able to defend itself at least as well as a PF could do it, and having an early detector can be key.